# Can I setup my Pow symlink so my domain is different than the name of the folder my project is in?

Tags: rack-pow

I have a project currently setup using Pow, and would like to change the domain to be something other than my projects root directory name.  For example, the root directory of my project is called project-refactor, and I want to change my domain from project-refactor.dev to project.dev without changing the directory's name.  I didn't see anything in the user manual covering this.

Answer (score 2):

Setup a new symlink and notice on the second line, you can define the name of the symlink by adding a second parameter, called project, or any name you want.  That is what will determine the domain name.

```
$ cd ~/.pow
$ ln -s /path/to/project-refactor project
$ open http://project.dev/
```

If left blank like is stated on the Pow website, the symlink just uses the same name as the folder you are linking to.